# How to sync all my Google calendars to iPhone with Exchange

Tags: iphone, calendar, ical, google-calendar, exchange-activesync

I have three calendars under "my calendars" in my Google account and I'd like to make it sync with my iPhone. This is a Google Apps for Work account so that I can have Microsoft Exchange enabled. The problem is, when I login to my account on iPhone as an Exchange account, I only see my default calendar and there's no option to choose other calendars.

I tried setup in https://calendar.google.com/calendar/syncselect and I can see all my calendars there if login as a normal Google account. However it doesn't work with Exchange account.

I don't want to give up Exchange because events and emails can be pushed to my iPhone instead of manually fetching them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out I missed one step:

- After login to Exchange, go to https://m.google.com/sync/settings and
  select iPhone (or other iOS devices) and choose calendars you want to
  sync on it.

This is really confusing that I can hardly tell the differences between this and the settings in https://calendar.google.com/calendar/syncselect

Answer (score 0):

1) On the iOS device, touch Settings.

2) Touch Mail, Contacts, Calendars.

3) Touch Add Account.

4) Touch Exchange.

**Note:** iOS 4.0+ allows multiple Exchange™ accounts. However, if you're on a device that doesn't let you add a second account, you can use IMAP to sync Gmail, CalDAV to sync Google Calendar, and CardDAV to sync contacts.

5) Enter the full Google Apps email address and a password and touch Next.

6) In the Server field, enter m.google.com.

7) Leave the Domain field blank.

8) In the Username field, enter the full Google Apps email address.

9) The password should already be in the Password field, if not, enter it again and touch Next

**Notes about passwords:**

Be sure that you have a strong password for your Google Apps account.

If you see an error message saying "Invalid Password", you may need to unlock your account by solving a short CAPTCHA challenge-response test. Go to https://www.google.com/accounts/UnlockCaptcha to allow access.

If you are a 2-Step Verification user, you should use an Application-specific password instead of a regular password in this field.

10) Select the Google services you want to sync, such as Mail, Contacts, and Calendars, and touch Save. To receive and respond to meeting requests on your device, you need to turn on Mail and Calendar here and New events in the Google Calendar settings. See Customize Mail, Calendar, and Contact settings for more information.

**Starting synchronization:** If Push is enabled on your device, synchronization will begin automatically. You can also open the Mail, Calendar, or Contacts app and wait a few seconds to start synchronization. If you recently signed up for Google Apps for Work, Education, or Government, it can take up to 24 hours before synchronization occurs.

Also Refer:- http://www.igeeksblog.com/how-to-sync-gmail-contacts-on-iphone/